# is there a way to use php with mininet like test use php for performance analysis?

Tags: php, python, sdn, mininet

I have a project that I'm working on it, I'm using Mininet to check and work on SDN's performance and now I would like to use PHP to check the performance analysis vs python. I did some searches but I couldn't any helpful things. Could you please let me know if there is a way to do that or even if that is possible?

Thank you in advance for your support and help.

Comment: Welcome! This question is confusing. Are you needing to write both php and python versions of the performance analysis? Or do you have code in php and python that you need to do a performance comparison of? Help us out here.

Comment: dear Kismert, I'm working with my teacher and he asked to do a performance comparison of time load with PHP vs Python in Mininet (network emulator), and I did search online I wasn't able to find any useful info about that. I the beginning I would like to know if there is a way to use PHP within mininet and then how to do it?!
and thank you for your reply, appreciate it.